# inherit or encapsulate View/Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to encapsulate a view/viewmodel into another view/viewmodel. The aim is to have a popup, slide panel or whatever you can think of common behaviour and insert a custom view/viewmodel into it.

I want to use the generic for doing that but I'm kind of stuck

the parent view model will look like that

```
public class SidePanelViewModel<T>
{
    public SidePanelViewModel(T enclosedViewModel)
    {
        EnclosedViewModel = enclosedViewModel;
    }

    public T EnclosedViewModel { get; private set; }
}
```

The parent view will be like that

```
... whatever design and behavior ...
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding EnclosedViewModel}"/>
... whatever design and behavior ...
```

In my mapping file I would like to put that but here is the problem:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WPFTests:SidePanelViewModel}">
  <WPFTests:SidePanelView />
</DataTemplate> 

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WPFTests:EnclosedViewModel}">
  <WPFTests:EnclosedView />
</DataTemplate>
```

This does not work because the constructor of the viewmodel SidePanelViewModel requiere a type to be created.

I guess what I want to do is having a view/viewmodel inherit from another view/viewmodel

Hope someone can help on that

Comment: Why do you need to use `<T>`? Can't you just use a regular `object` or some kind of shared base such as `IViewModel` or `ViewModelBase`?

Comment: @Rachel I can't beleive I miss that!!! I guess too much fancy technology made me a little bit dumb... answer it if you want I'll validate it as a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to use `<T>`?

Can't you just use a regular `object` or some kind of shared base such as `IViewModel` or `ViewModelBase`?

Answer (score 0):

Working with generic classes in WPF can be quite painful sometimes ..

I would recommend you to create a base (abstract) class that implements the default behavior for your (virtual, of course) methods.

Comment: I know that, and that's what I had in mind at the begining but I need to inherit of the view as well, and I don't know how to do that

Comment: But the ViewModel / View responsibilities are different. Actually the ViewModel just updates the bindings. It doesn't call any view methods.

If you want your views to have a common behavior, implement a different class for your views

Comment: sorry i guees i was not clear enough. I want to the look of the parent view as well not just the behavior of the view model. the child view/viemodel will be sitting in the parent view/viewmodel and be decorated by it. in the parent view i will have some border image button... and i don't want to rewrite them each time in the child view

Comment: I would recommend creating a ControlTemplate which you will apply to every view, because you cannot inherit from visual elements(elements with xaml) in WPF.